# Alternative to restart phoenix.server without quitting

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there any way to restart the `mix phoenix.server` besides of quitting (e.g. by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> twice or abort etc.) and starting it again?

The background for this is: I use foreman to start the phoenix server plus test runner etc. If I have to quit the server, everything is killed and I have to completely restart foreman. If I could just trigger a restart of the phoenix.server job everything else could remain running.

Since I use tmux and run the foreman commands in different panes this would help a lot. A command triggered via command line is also fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start your server in an `iex` session with

`iex -S mix phx.server`

Then stop, recompile and start the application with:

```
Application.stop(:your_app)
recompile()
Application.ensure_all_started(:your_app)
```

This should pick up any code changes and recreate the application supervision tree.

Comment: Thanks. I actually added a function inside `.iex.exs` for that now so I only have to type `App.restart()`.

Comment: can't figure out what will :you_app be, I get 'appanme.app' no such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

you can also do `:init.restart()`